# Finding MSBs and LSBs of a string

Tags: go, byte, xor

I need to do following operations in Go:

1. Concatenate 2 strings
2. Compute MD5 hash of the concatenated string (128-bit array)
3. Apply an XOR operator to the 64 LSBs and the 64 MSBs on MD5 hash.

I could compute MD5 hash of the string using "crypto/md5" package, but having trouble implementing step #3.
Here is the code I came up with which is not correct I think and didn't see any links to get MSBs and LSBs from a string.

```
func GenerateHashKey(s1 string, s2 string) string {
    if s1 == "" {
        return ""
    }

    data := []byte(s1 + s2)
    md5sum := md5.Sum(data)
    
    // 0: uint32
    lsb := bytes.NewBuffer(md5sum[:9]) // 0-8
    msb := bytes.NewBuffer(md5sum[9:]) // 9-16
    return msb ^ lsb; //This results in an error
}
```

Here is a corresponding working Java code that I need to translate to Go.

```
//input is a concatenated string
byte[] str = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] md5sum = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(str);
long lsb =
ByteBuffer.wrap(md5sum).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong(0);
long msb =
ByteBuffer.wrap(md5sum).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong(8);
return msb ^ lsb;
```

Comment: Bitwise operators only work in integer values, you cannot apply a `^` to `bytes.Buffer` struct. The function signature returns a string, what kind of string you expect to get from `msb ^ lsb`?

Comment: Right. I am not sure how can I extract msb and lsb and perform XOR operation on them. I have updated the question and added working Java code to provide more details.

Comment: The go std library has the `encoding/binary` package, which translates that code directly (provided you fix the slice indexes, since you need to split the slice at byte 8, not 9). You still aren't returning a string from the function. What do you want go return there?

Comment: You are right about the index. It should be 8. Will fix that and check out encoding/binary package. I want my go function to return string and know my code is erroneous, which is why need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the return type is a string, but what does that mean? How do you want to encode the raw bytes into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a bitwise operator on a `bytes.Buffer`, it only applies to integer values. You can use the [`encoding/binary`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary) package to convert the bytes into suitable 64 bit values to XOR, and use the little endian byte order here as shown in the java code provided.

Once you have the value, you can format the returned string as desired with `fmt.Sprintf` or the `strconv` package.

```
func GenerateHashKey(s1 string, s2 string) string {
    data := []byte(s1 + s2)
    md5sum := md5.Sum(data)

    lsb := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(md5sum[:8])
    msb := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(md5sum[8:])
    return strconv.FormatUint(lsb^msb, 10)
}
```

Comment: Just a small tweak in the return statement did the trick for me :                    return strconv.Itoa(int((msb ^ lsb)))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution

Comment: Note that your change will format negative numbers into the string, which seems strange for a hash value, and will truncate on 32 bit systems.